# How to clean up mysql out in python?

Tags: python, mysql

Hi everyone in php when you fetch data from a mysql database and echo it out you get just whats in the selected row . Say i have a database named workers and a table called names
and names have 5 names in it mic,joe,ashley,lee,and jean. Using `SELECT names from names where name = 'jean'` and then echoed out the name php would print out jean but in python it would print out `('jean',)` how can i fix this so that i can compare the names entered by the user with the names in the database.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","fgnfgnfgnfgn","workers" )
cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT names from names where name = 'jean'")

while True:
  record = data = cursor.fetchone()
  if not record: break
   print record
  if data == "jean":
print "its like php"
 elif data != "jean":
     print "its not like php"


db.close()
```

Comment: How are you outputting the results?

Comment: Its unclear if you are asking a python question or a php question.

Comment: @deceze  i used cursor.fetchone().

Comment: @cdburgess its a python question i need to be able to remove the   ('  ',) from around jean.

Comment: stupid question, but is 's' in `SELECT names..` a typo? IOW shouldn't it be `SELECT name...` ?

Comment: @Crayon Violent yes it should be name not names sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fetchone() and fetch_row() return objects of type called [tuple](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences).

You can use indexes to access elements of tuples, `print data[0]`

Answer (score 2):

```
if data[0] == "jean"
```